# undefined vs unassigned variable in typescript

Tags: typescript

I don't understand why doesn't typescript compiler classify `undefined` with `unassigned` variable.

```
class MyClass {
   N1: number;
   N2: number;
}

var mc = new MyClass();
mc.N2 = mc.N1;
alert(mc.N2); // output: undefined
```

Why isn't the output `Use of unassigned variable 'mc.N1'`?

It cannot be `undefined` because I've defined clearly. It's a number (a number exactly without a default value).

Also, `undefined` mean: we don't have variable `mc.N2`.

My question is: Do I misunderstand something? If yes, please correct me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is your code in javascript:

```
var MyClass = (function () {
    function MyClass() {
    }
    return MyClass;
})();
var mc = new MyClass();
mc.N2 = mc.N1;
alert(mc.N2);
```

> Why isn't the output Use of unassigned variable 'mc.N1'?

There is not a such state unassigned in javascript.

> It cannot be undefined because I've defined clearly. It's a number (a
>   number exactly without a default value).

In javascript, a variable is eiter undefined which is not assigned any value,
or null which is a value as well, or any string, ingeger or float, date or bool.
however declaring `number` has no effect on the value of variable. it is typescript internal affair.

> Also, undefined mean: we don't have variable mc.N2.

Undefined does not mean, you don't have variable, it means mc.N2 a variable with has assigned no value yet

Comment: ya, based on your answer, I know typescript compiler doesn't customize the error message (changing `undefined` to `unassigned`). Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You misunderstand the meaning of the undefined. It does not mean that the property was defined in code. Lets read directly from MDN:

> A variable that has not been assigned a value is of type undefined.

See here for more info [undefined](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/undefined)

And this is exactly what happened in your code. The value of the mc.N1 has never been assigned.

Hope this helps.